# How modify the content of a html table with with a ng-click event outside the table that get data from a RESTFUL API

Tags: html, angularjs

How can I fill the table using an Angujarjs' click event from outside the table. A click event in a div or button using ng-click get data from a web API and it updates a angular model that should be use to fill the table.

So far the process to click and collect data is working but the table is not being filled. The ng-repeat is not working.

I have now this code and it is not working:

NG  Controller

```
//showParticipantCollectedData is working and I get the data from the API
   var DataCollectionSetupController = function ($scope, metricRepository, participantRepository, dataCollectionSetupRepository) {
        ....
        $scope.showParticipantCollectedData = function (petsId) {
            $scope.collectedDataByPetsId = dataCollectionSetupRepository.getCollectedDataFromPets(petsId);
        };

 .....

    }
```

View

```
....
   <button data-ng-click="showParticipantCollectedData(100)">Test</button>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th width="4%">#</th>
                                    <th width="40%">Variable Name</th>
                                    <th width="23%">Value</th>
                                    <th width="33%">Measure</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr data-ng-repeat="measure in collectedDataByPetsId">
                                    <td>{{measure.Id}}</td>
                                    <td>{{measure.Value}}</td>
                                    <td>{{measure.MetricId}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are showing appears to be synchronous, but I would expect your data API to return a promise right?

So I would think this line:

```
$scope.collectedDataByPetsId = 
       dataCollectionSetupRepository.getCollectedDataFromPets(petsId);
```

Should actually look something like this:

```
dataCollectionSetupRepository.getCollectedDataFromPets(petsId)
  .then(function(result){
    $scope.collectedDataByPetsId = result.data;
  });
```

Perhaps you are actually binding your property to a promise rather than the result of the asynchronous API call?